# After commenting out virtualnameHost on passenger_vhosts.conf my apache2 is only resolving to one domain

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have to hosts (domains) that i have added on the passenger_vhosts.conf.
I had namevirtualhost*:80 on my conf file and i was able to resolve for two domain, after updating my apache2 the namevirtualHost had to effect so i commented it out but my problem was that both hosts are now resolving to the one domain\host.

Host file configuration:

[image]

passenger_vhosts.conf:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, all i needed to do was configure my virtualhost as follows.

```
<VirtualHost app1.co.za:80>
ServerName app1.co.za
DocumentRoot /home/repos/app1/public
```